# Google Map urls functions unsupported

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-urls

we want to control Google Maps on Android/IOS devices via urls, and we've looked through the docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#display_a_map

These are the functions we need but cannot find in the document:
1. Color Scheme(automatic, day, night)
2. Map type(default, satelite, terrain), Map detail(transist, traffic, bicycling, 3D, Street View)
3. Route options (avoid highways, avoid tolls, avoid ferries)
4. Search along route

Comment: All mentioned here sounds like a new feature requests. Open [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:195646), post your feature request and let see what they answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it applies to your use case/implementation, you might want to consider using [Maps SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/intro). This will generally handle [styled maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling) (e.g color scheme, etc.), [map types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#map_types) (e.g terrain, satellite, etc), map details like [Street View](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/streetview) and [Traffic Layers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#the_traffic_layer).

However for the route options, you need to use a separate web service - [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro).

Hope this helps!